# LibreNMS Installation

Tags: command-line, php

I'm installing a LibreNMS server and when I issue the command "php addhost.php 10.2.1.21 NetManage v2c" i get an error message saying "Could not open input file: addhost.php" also tried it from the root user doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just run :

```
./addhost.php 10.2.1.21
```

Comment: And you must be in the LibreNMS install directory (default /opt/librenms) to do this... :-)